# Windows API BackupRead failing with error 50 on Windows Storage Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, winapi, backup

We have a backup application that uses the Windows API BackupRead. It works correctly on Windows Server 2003, 2008, 2008 R2. It does not work on Storage Server 2008 R2. It always fails with error 50 - The request is not supported. The documentation for BackupRead gives no indication that it will not work with Storage Server 2008 R2.

Anyone else have any experience using this API on Storage Server 2008 R2?  Did you need to make any changes to your use of the API in order for it to work?

Comment: How are you using the API now?

Answer (score 1):

[Known problem between Windows 2008 and non-2008 volumes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973278/en-us).  Hot fix resolves it.